# Python Pandas histogram with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram to represent several elements of a dataframe.

The dataframe is like follows:

```
        Freq
Item 1   25
Item 2   35
```

I am trying to make a histogram with Item 1 and Item 2 along the bottom, and the numbers representing the height (on the y axis) as a frequency (note that I do not want cumulative frequency).

I have tried this:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tour_adjust, orient='index')
plt.hist(dataframe, bins=10)
plt.show()
```

and I am getting results like this:
[Image showing the histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHmXo.png)

(Actual result only differs from desired as per the number of elements in the dataframe)

As oppose to the desired result, seen here:

[Image showing the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vribJ.png)

I have tried with orient='index' and without it, but the two are both incorrect and not what I am looking for.

Comment: It looks like you need to adjust your bins. try: `plt.hist(dataframe, bins=2)` and update us with the results.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DyDnvV9, definitely closer to the result, but still no labels along the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your numbers are already frequencies, than maybe what you're looking for is not the `hist` plot, but simply a `bar` plot?

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

### Update

You can also plot directly from a dataframe, like in [this example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val':[10, 30, 20]})
>>> ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0)
```

Comment: This does make sense, except this is for a piece of submitted work, and a requirement is that it must be a histogram.

Comment: If your data is already frequency then a bar plot will actually be the histogram plot you're looking for.

Comment: I amended my answer, it originally read box plot, while I meant bar plot.

Comment: This is almost there, how do I then label the bottom of the graph with the names of the items? Currently: https://imgur.com/a/CJqqcS1 I would like to replace the numbers on the x axis with the names of the items, the code is:

plt.bar([i for i, _ in enumerate(tour_list)], [i for i, _ in enumerate(tour_vals)])

Comment: Try plotting straight from the dataframe, see my updated answer

Comment: please don't copy again

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: andrzejwp's UPDATE Section was created when i post this answer... I think It was a copy..

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer when @JordanDalby replied that he was looking for a histogram, when I came to realize I mentioned a boxplot instead of barplot. The code I copied is from pandas docs.